# How to build warfile using previous versions of source files?

Tags: build-process

Do I need CVS repository viewer?

Comment: http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#goal

Answer (score 0):

I think you are done successfully on set your class path of Java.

```
c:>jar -cf MyWebTest.war *
```

I will creates `.war` file in C drive of your local computer.